ICP sensor current regulator circuit using lm334
I am trying to create a current source circuit for ICP Accelerometer using LM334 Circuit.
I am using 24v, 2A supply to power up the schematic. I'm attaching the circuit I designed . The sensor specifications are
Excitation voltage - 18-30VDC,
constant current excitation - 2-20mA,
output bias voltage - 8-12VDC
I got this design fabricated into pcb board, but when I connect sensor and check the output in oscilloscope , it is only showing 7V DC, what could be the problem in the schematic. could anyone help me to sort out the issue. I am also having confusion in the wiring part of LM334. does this wiring schema will excite the accelerometer.


What is connected to J5? LM334 wiring is incorrect, have a look at figure 13 in the datasheet.

A rookie mistake by the designer. +24 volts feeds the input of the 7915 and 7905 negative voltage regulators in the expectation that they will happily work: -

Here's a close up of the 7915 (negative) regulator: -

And, here's a close up of the 7815 (positive) regulator: -

As you can see both regulator types receive positive 24 volts when in fact the 7915 and 7905 circuits require a negative input voltage for their supplies.

I am also having confusion in the wiring part of LM334

Please explain what that confusion is.

my doubt is whether the circuit arrangement of LM334 is really going to excite the sensor??

@priya please don't ignore the elephant in the room. Please link the sensor data sheet.

Sorry I didn't understand

The elephant in the room = the basic mistake in how you have used the 7915 and 7905 voltage regulators.

I isolated those regulators from PCB and now I'm providing negative voltages to both of the regulators externally from Dual Source PS, but still there is no output from the circuit..

I've explained what was wrong with the regulators. If you now expect something more you would be better placed to raise a new post.

@priya if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question.
